# Dart: Why do we declare only one type when using generics?

Tags: flutter, generics, dart

Consider this example:

```
typedef ItemWidgetBuilder<T> = Widget Function(Buildcontext context, T item);
```

note: *This code snippet is just the first example I could find and has nothing to do with `typedef`*.

I still cannot wrap my head around type declaration inside `< >` and the documentation I could find is not thorough when it comes to that, why do we only declare the generic type `T` and not the `BuildContext` type since it takes both? Like so:

```
ItemWidgetBuilder<BuildContext, T> = Widget Function(Buildcontext context, T item);
```

Comment: In `<>` you put *generic* types, i.e. not concrete. `T` can be any type (int, String, MyClass, etc) so it's generic and should be in `<>`. `BuildContext` can't be any other type, it's always BuildContext so it's concrete and shouldn't be in `<>`

Comment: @Pavel Thanks for the answer, so if I'm not wrong, I can put two generics since the function takes two parameters? I.e. `<T, S>`

Comment: @TersterWordp yes, you can use any number of generic parameters

Comment: @Pavel you said *In `<>` you put generic types*, what about `Map<String, int>` or `List<String>` these are not generic and yet they're inside `< >`?